# How to get the URL of a webpage in PHP?

Tags: php, url, dynamic, server

I need to get the URL of a website, but how do we do this in PHP?

For example there's a URL `www.example.com/page.php?var=value`, the URL is dynamic, I need to get the `var=value` portion of the URL. The URL is some other website so cannot use `$_SERVER[]` variables.

I cannot parse the URL since `parse_url()` requires an URL to be specified and I don't know the what the value of `var` will be, I want to fetch the URL using PHP script and then parse it.

Is there any way we can do this in PHP?

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/parse_url

Answer (score 1):

`parse_url` will parse the URL and return its components.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
<?php

    $url = 'www.example.com/page.php?var=value';
    $query_string = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY );

    echo $query_string;
?>
```

> Output:
>
> var=value

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've updated my question can you help it?

Answer (score 0):

With `parse_url()` and `parse_str()` you can get the parameters:

```
$url = "www.example.com/page.php?var=value";
$urlParts= parse_url($url); // Separates the url
parse_str($urlParts['query'], $parameters);// Get the part you actually need it and create a array

var_dump($parameters) // Your parameters
```

**Update:**

Replace the var_dump to:

```
foreach($parameters as $key => $value) {
    echo $key." = ".$value."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've updated my question can you help it?

Comment: actually with the code you can catch every parameter and do what you want with them. Updated with an example.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm not asking about how can I parse an URL, I'm asking about how can I fetch an URL. For `parse_url()` to work, there must be an URL specified, how do I fetch an URL so that I can parse it?

Comment: So you dont even have a `$url`? What are trying to achieve here, be more especific in your question. You want to know every possible url in a random site?

Comment: The code works with any url and we can even check if there is any query parameter before print the values.

Comment: Actually after researching it looks like there isn't any way to grab the URL of a website using PHP on the fly.

Comment: Your code does work as it should, what I trying to say is, we cannot simply grab the URL of a website using PHP. `parse_url` requires an URL to be supplied, but how do we fetch the URL to supply it to `parse_url(). For example we have, `www.example.com/page.php?var=v&var2=v2`, the domain, the value of `var` is known but the value of `var2` is not known, so my question was how do we fetch the URL so that we can get the value of `var2`?

Comment: I'm still confused sorry. How are you getting just a part of an url? You have a string like `www.example.com/page.php?var=v` and assume there could be a `var2` parameter? Unless you already gave up, could you update the question properly? An example would help.

Comment: Example: Let's say `Youtube.com`, to access any video, you can simply type `www.youtube.com/watch?v=video_id`, `video_id` being the `id` of that video. Similarly the website `www.example.com/page.php?var=v&var2=v2`, I can access their content by supplying the value of `var`, but unlike youtube, they have a second variable `var2` that is randomly generated. So to access their content, I need to supply both the variables. `var` is known since it is the `id` of the content but `var2` is not known. So I want to fetch the URL to get the value of `var2` so that I can pass it along the URL.

Comment: I see. But how could the second parameter be random anyway? It should mean something to the page, or is something like a token? And if it really doesn't, unless not for what you need, why you just don't fill `var2` with anything? I mean you know the name of the parameter and possible results like you know you must have a `id` right? IE: `youtube.com/watch?v=video_id&t=10 //because i know "t" means time and i put any value on it, but i really only need the page with that id`. Is there any relation between the first and the second parameter?

Comment: Whatever is your problem doesn't looks like any code will help you, Since the second parameter it's just random.